# How to convert 1 column records of dynamic table into hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink

Edit : I tried all the solutions given Below ..there are 3 more external files ..I think they are overriding the setting ..I am pasting them too below

I have a dynamic table in Jquery .I want to make its 3rd column records MZillaID Hyperlink

Here is my Code :

```
function getErrorStatusList() {

    $.ajax({
        //data comes in response
        success: function (response) {

            obj =  response.d;
            var output = "<table class='table'><tr><th>Serial No.</th><th>UFZillaID</th><th>MZillaID</th><th>Status</th></tr>";

            for (var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++) {
                output += "<tr><td>" + (x + 1) + "</td><td>" + obj[x].IssueID + "</td><td class='myclass'>" + obj[x].EMID + "</td><td>" + obj[x].EMStatus + "</td></tr>";
            }
            output += "</table>";
            $("#result").append(output);

        },

    });
```

I want to make 
    
records Hyperlink ... Can we do it in CSS /Jquery ??i Created a class(myclass) on particlar column .But I dont know how to procedd . record for this column are already a hyperlink but it is overridden by other css .

Please suggest .Any Help would be helpful

Comment: `<td><a href'"+ url + "'>" + obj[x].EMStatus + "</a></td>` this should work if i get you right

Comment: It works only when Mouse Hover on data . I want to make Hyperlink visible with Mouse Hover

Comment: `<td><a href'"+ url + "' style="text-decoration:underline;">" + obj[x].EMStatus + "</a></td>` try this one

Comment: But what will i add in url ??obj[x].EMID is itself a url ...And this code is also not woring ...

Comment: `<td><a href'"+ obj[x].EMID + "' style="text-decoration:underline;">" + obj[x].EMStatus + "</a></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append anchor `<a>` tags inside 3rd column-  `<td>`

```
output += "<tr><td>" + (x + 1) + "</td><td>" 
         + obj[x].IssueID + "</td><td class='myclass'><a  href='"+obj[x].EMID +"' style='text-decoration:underline;'>" 
                                                   here^
         + obj[x].EMID + "</a></td><td>" + obj[x].EMStatus + "</td></tr>";
                       here^
```

or after you append use **[`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)**,

```
$("#result").append(output);
$("#result table td:eq(2)").wrap('<a href="'+url+'" style="text-decoration:underline;"></a>');
```

CSS :

```
a{
  cursor:pointer;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZgWN/1/)

Comment: No it is not working properly ..data is apeears as hyperlink only when mouse Hovers on them

Comment: I am a bit new ... do it need to css in jquery or in aspx ??

Comment: I did it ..In firebug ..It says  SyntaxError: "missing ; before statement"...j[x].IssueID + "</td><td class='myclass'><a style="text-decoration:underline;">

Comment: I also change "style="text-decoration:underline;" to 'style="text-decoration:underline;' ..but then it is not working

Comment: I put Your jsfiddle working Code in My Jquery ..But still Hyperlink is only coming on Mouse Hover..I have 3 more external css in my aspx ...does they override the settings ?

Comment: YES!!!!!...HyperLink appears ....thank Heaven ...But it is in black ..Can we make it Blue ??

Comment: NO NO ..It again fails ...hyerlink works on static data ...But on Dynamic data . it again failed

Comment: any errors in console? Post the whole code your are using in your question

Comment: it should be <a href=""> not <a url="">

Comment: yes ...Check this jsfiddle.net/5ZgWN/2 ..this is working ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

shaunakde gave me Solution ... I am posting the full Working Code

```
function getErrorStatusList() {
    var serve = JSON.stringify({ program: $("#selpros option:selected").text() });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UFZillaErrorStatus.aspx/GetErrorStatusList",
        data: serve,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#result").empty();
            obj = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            var output = "<table class='table'><tr><th>Serial No.</th><th>UFZillaID</th><th>MZillaID</th><th>Status</th></tr>";

            for (var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++) {

                output += "<tr><td>" + (x + 1) + "</td><td>" + obj[x].IssueID + "</td><td class='myclass' style='text-decoration:underline;'>" + obj[x].EMID + "</a></td><td>" + obj[x].EMStatus + "</td></tr>";
            }
            output += "</table>";
            $("#result").append(output);

        },
        error: function () { alert("Server Error!!"); }

    });
```